# How to limit duplicated rows

Tags: sql, oracle, select, duplicates

I would like help regarding an SQL query.
Looking around the site, I found several code snippets to return duplicate rows.
Here is the one I went with:

```
select unumber, name, localid
from table1
where unumber
in (select unumber from table1 group by unumber having count (*) > 1 )
order by unumber
```

which works fine, however, in the table I have other columns as well, like timestamp etc.
As such, when I run the query I indeed get the duplicate rows, however, I get the duplicates several times due to different timestamps for example.
Is there any way to limit the results to 'unique' duplicate rows only?

[image]

Hope this makes sense!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Most people here want table data as formatted text, not images...

Comment: Add `DISTINCT`. As simple as that.

Comment: Or just add `UNIQUE` since that's the word you used in your description; [either is valid](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6), though I don't think I've ever actually seen `UNIQUE` being used. (Or `ALL`, for that matter...)

Answer (score 3):

For what you describe, you can just use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct unumber, name, localid
from table1
where unumber in (select unumber from table1 group by unumber having count (*) > 1 )
order by unumber;
```

However, I would be more likely to write this using window functions:

```
select unumber, name, localid
from (select t1.*,
             count(*) over (partition by unumber) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by unumber, name, localid order by unumber) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where cnt > 1 and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify why you would use the latter option?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I tried out both methods (distinct & window), however, I get records that are not duplicates. E.g. the 'unumber' appears to be unique and there is no pair for it.

Comment: @WynDiesel - because it only hits the table once. There are trade-offs but that's usually more efficient than hitting it twice - once to find the `unumber` values, then a second time to get the related data for those values.